# Ubuntu does not boot, kernel panic - not syncung: Fatal exeption in interrupt

Tags: boot, grub2

My VM box all of a sudden stopped working. When I start the system the following message appears.

[image]

Then either initialization options retrieve the same error as bellow.

[image]

I suspect it is because I ran out of space on my VM box storage because I'd been receiving a notification telling on the short space (500mb left if I remember correctly) but unfortunately I could not make any remove command on the grub shell.

I do not mind losing the entire machine, apart from my www/ folder, so some possible solutions came to my mind and would be much appreciated:

Delete some files from the machine - restricted to the actions of the grub.
Manage to recover my www/ folder to another Linux ubuntu server.
Be able to get to cmd and perform the apt-get autoremove - or something similar.
Any other idea is also welcomed (given the desperation state I am in now)

Comment: From logs I have it appears as `linux 5.8.0-55-generic` was released somewhere  around 2021-06-09, i.e. fairly recently; did your problems start then possibly? Try to boot using either of the `linux 5.8.0-53-generic` entries in your boot menu.

Comment: Yes, the problems started last week, around 2021-06-19. I tried to start using any option, normal mode, safety mode, linux 5.8.0-53-generic and linux 5.8.0-55-generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual machine...

Download a Ubuntu installation ISO, or use one you have already.

Make that ISO the primary boot disk for the VM, and the full disk a secondary disk.
Boot, you should be able to access the secondary disk.

Now, you might need to set up a share or other means to copy out the data you need.
I suggest you Google that.